# Problem with sitting up Pi3 (Headless)

Tags: ssh, windows, setup, putty

I tried to setup my Pi via WiFi .. so I installed NOOBS I connected to a monitor to see if it can boot (but I do not have Keyboards & Mouse) so I connect my Pi with the router and I found its IP on my PC (Windows 8.1) so I used Putty and I wrote the IP of Pi but it says 'connection refused' ..why ?

Comment: You need a keyboard and monitor to do the initial setup of noobs. You can download Raspbian and burnb the image to your SD card. Raspbian can be setup remotely via SSH.

Comment: @SteveRobillard Thank you, but I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=toWBmUsWD6M

Comment: The tutorial you linked to appears to be using Raspbian not noobs.

Comment: FWIW, Raspbian is easier to set up headlessly than NOOBS